# Connect to SphinxQL through Linux command-line

Tags: mysql, command-line, search-engine, sphinx

I am trying to connect to **SphinxQL** server through Linux **command-line** this way:

```
> mysql -P 9306

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My Sphinx config file has 2 listen entries:

```
listen                  = 9312
listen                  = 9306:mysql41
```

searchd daemon is running:

```
> ps ax | grep searchd
10727 ?        S      0:00 /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd
10728 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd
```

Regular search queries work perfectly:

```
> /usr/local/sphinx/bin/search StackOverflow | more

Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
index 'test1': query 'StackOverflow ': returned 2 matches of 2 total in 0.009 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=1788212, weight=1797
        id=1788212
...
```

So, what I am doing wrong? How can I get access to SphinxQL console?

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specifying host address I got MySQL console instead of SphinxQL console:
This is weird ...:

> mysql  -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306
Welcome to the MySQL monitor...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

the 'mysql' client, will totally ignore the -P param, if it detects mysql is running on a unix-socket. So really even though you ask for the sphinxQL port, you are connecting to mysql

Use

```
mysql -P9306 --protocol=tcp
```

to tell the client to ignore the socket.

Pro Tip:

```
mysql -P9306 --protocol=tcp --prompt='sphinxQL> '
```

which serves as a useful ongoing reminder you are connected to sphinx not mysql :)

Comment: If you've got an old version of Sphinx but a newer version of MySQL then you might get a message saying `ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)`. You need to add an extra option to the command: `mysql -P9306 --protocol=tcp --prompt='sphinxQL> ' --skip-secure-auth`

Answer (score 12):

Works for me:

```
mysql -P 9306 -h 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this recently. I was able to get in to Sphinx via the mysql shell by commenting out the `listen` configuration that didn't specify MySQL. This may not work for you, if you still need to get to `searchd` via the API.

Comment: I did it, and restarted searchd daemon. But I throughts the same errors. Nevertheless it seems I could enter, using "mysql -P 9306 -p" command and root MySQL password, but it does identify as MySQL console. It is weird. When querying mysql> SELECT * FROM test1 LIMIT 0,10; it responds: ERROR 1064 (42000): index test1: fullscan requires extern docinfo

Comment: Hmm, that is odd, that error message (about requiting extern docinfo' is a sphinx error, not a mysql error. Which suggests you are connecting to searchd. What version of mysql is reported when first connect, it should show the server version when connecting.

Comment: Fixed. I was connecting to MySQL instead of SphinxQL. My command lacked an important modifier: --protocol=tcp. Thanks!