# sphinxsearch: ERROR: index 'ad1_offers': sql_connect: Access denied for user

Tags: sphinx

Mysql client have access, password is true. The mysql user have all privileges on all databases:

- GRANT SELECT,
- INSERT,
- UPDATE,
- DELETE,
- CREATE,
- DROP,
- RELOAD,
- SHUTDOWN,
- PROCESS,
- REFERENCES,
- INDEX,
- ALTER,
- SHOW DATABASES,
- SUPER,
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,  LOCK TABLES,
- EXECUTE,
- REPLICATION SLAVE,  REPLICATION CLIENT,
- CREATE VIEW,  SHOW VIEW,
- CREATE ROUTINE,  ALTER ROUTINE,
- CREATE USER,
- EVENT,
- TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'ad1'@'%'

I have errors:

```
/usr/bin/indexer   --all
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'ad1_offers'...
ERROR: index 'ad1_offers': sql_connect: Access denied for user ad1'@'192.168.0.177' (using password: YES) (DSN=mysql://ad1:***@192.168.0.177:3306/ad1).
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start
Starting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 192.168.0.177:9312
listening on 192.168.0.177:9306
precaching index 'ad1_offers'
WARNING: index 'ad1_offers': preload: failed to open /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/    ad1_offers.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
FATAL: no valid indexes to serve ERROR.
```

spnix.conf:

```
    type                    = mysql

    sql_host                = 192.168.0.177
    sql_user                = ad1
    sql_pass                = ....
    sql_db                  = ad1
    sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: index 'ad1_offers': sql_connect: Access denied for user ad1'@'192.168.0.177' (using password: YES) (DSN=mysql://ad1:***@192.168.0.177:3306/ad1).

That means indexer can't even CONNECT to mysql. Its more about the user existing and the password being right, than the actual permissions the user has.

Can you use the `mysql` command line client to connect to your database?

Comment: the mysql client have access to Db ad1 by user ad1 with pass .... from host (localhost), so mysql user have ALL GRANT PRIVILEGES

Comment: The sphinx.con is :         sql_host                = 192.168.0.177
        sql_user                = ad1
        sql_pass                = ....
        sql_db                  = ad1
        sql_port                = 3306

Comment: # mysql -u ad1 -p -h 192.168.0.177
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 85899
Server version: 5.5.46-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Comment: also , with root login/password access denied

Comment: Maybe try adding --protocol=tcp to the mysql command line, `mysql -u ad1 -p -h 192.168.0.177 --protocol=tcp` - thats an even better simulation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126948/connect-to-sphinxql-through-linux-command-line (sphinx wont use the socket, that mysql client may default to )

Answer (score 0):

in my case, when I had such a mistake it's just was a wrong password for MySQL.
my users's password contained signs of type like `'#'` or `'!'`.
after I removed these characters from the password everything started working!